Flutter just_audio oga cause 1002 Unsupported URL
Problem:
I forced to download voice messages in .oga format.
As handler I use fork of voice_message_package (which depends on just_audio).
Android works fine. IOS - error 1002 Unsupported URL.
Question: Is there any optimal solution without file conversion?
Answer: No - https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1748

Not very good, but the only working solution:
Convert .oga to .m4a by ffmpeg_kit_flutter lib:
final oldPath = file.path;
final pathFragments = file.path.split('.')..last = 'm4a';
final newPath = pathFragments.join('.');
await FFmpegKit.execute('-i $oldPath -c:a aac -b:a 128k $newPath');
final resultAudio = File(newPath);

Add scheme for iOS:
'file://${file.path}'

